L2 WiFi-to-Eth Bridge: Drops Internet Connection
Using Ubuntu x64 Server 23.10: I have an L2 bridge that links a WiFi adapter in 4addr mode to an Ethernet jack. The WiFi adapter is meant to connect to my gateway, the Ethernet jack should then provide internet access to the client.
I connect the WiFi adapter to my gateway, but after adding the WiFi adapter to the L2 bridge I lose my network connection. This makes sense, but how do I re-give the WiFi adapter/bridge internet access via the WiFi adapter once it gets added to the bridge?
Thank you for your help!

Does your gateway support WDS (4 address) mode? Is your gateway configured to talk to your Wi-Fi adapter's MAC address in WDS mode?

Yes it is, I’ve connected the WiFi adapter to my gateway in 4addr mode before adding it to the L2 bridge
